# A functional interface that extends other can't - can't assign constructor reference to it - Is it compiler bug?

Tags: java, method-reference

In the simple code below i can see to 'Factory' interfaces, the only different between them is that `Factory0Bad` extends `Supplier`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public static interface Factory0Bad<T> extends Supplier<T> {
    T get();
}

@FunctionalInterface
public static interface Factory0Good<T>  {
    T get();
}

public static class Handler {}
public static class HandlerA extends Handler {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // this line compiles
    Factory0Good<? extends Handler> good = HandlerA::new;

    // this does not!
    Factory0Bad<? extends Handler> bad = HandlerA::new;
}
```

So the line

```
Factory0Good<? extends Handler> good = HandlerA::new;
```

is accepted by the compiler (1.8.0u05), but this line

```
Factory0Bad<? extends Handler> bad = HandlerA::new;
```

is not.

Why is this? What am I missing here? Is it a bug in javac?

Comment: It compiles fine with javac 1.8.0_40.

Comment: javac 1.8.0_25 doesn't like it.

Comment: @FilipBulovic, JohnKugelman You are right:it fails on 1.8.0_05 and succeeds on 1.8.0_{40,45}

Answer (score 1):

```
 // this does not!
        // 1.8.0_05 - fails
        // 1.8.0_40 - succeeds
        // 1.8.0_45 - succeeds
        Factory0Bad<? extends Handler> bad = HandlerA::new;
```